# how to add contact using rest api of sms global

Tags: php, sms

i want to add my user in sms global contact using rest api
i refer the below link 
http://www.smsglobal.com/rest-api/

and for rest api use below package
https://github.com/smsglobal/rest-api-client-php-5.2

i try to add contact but contact not add in sms global contact .

can i add contact using rest api?if yes than how to add this contact.

Comment: First you could starting by adding your current code to your question (the relevant parts). How else do you expect us to help with it?

Comment: I m not getting any code for add contact to sms global

Comment: so it's possible or not?If possible than how can add using rest api

Comment: By "adding your current code" I was referring to the code you yourself implemented to add those contacts. If you do not show _how_ you try to do that (by using what code) we cannot help you fix that code. Sorry.